# Finishing release pushes to all remote repository

Tags: git, git-flow

I have 2 branches stored in bitbucket `master` and `develop` branches. I'm currently implementing gitflow, then I've used `post-receive` on the remote repository, then I have `post-merge` on my local to automate pushing changes to remote repository. It works well on develop branch, but finishing a release branch pushes back to all remote repository when it should be only pushing to production.

`develop branch = staging`

`master branch = production`

I have done this on the other project with same setup and it works well. Unsure why it's happening here.

Here's a sample post-receive script on the server

```
#!/bin/bash
# Allowed branch
DEPLOY_ALLOWED_BRANCH="develop"

while read oldrev newrev refname
do

    BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    NEWREV="$newrev"

    if [[ "$DEPLOY_ALLOWED_BRANCH" == "$BRANCH" ]]; then
        GIT_WORK_TREE="/var/www/project"
        GIT_DIR="/var/www/git/project.git"

        git --git-dir="$GIT_DIR" --work-tree="$GIT_WORK_TREE" checkout -f "${BRANCH}" || exit 1
        git reset --hard "$NEWREV" || exit 1

        exit 0
    fi
done
```

Here's a sample post-merge on my local

```
#!/bin/bash

export DEPLOY_BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref HEAD)
export DEPLOY_BRANCH_DEV="develop"
export DEPLOY_BRANCH_PROD="master"

if [ "${DEPLOY_BRANCH_DEV}" == "$DEPLOY_BRANCH" ]; then
  git push staging develop -f
  exit 0
fi

if [ "${DEPLOY_BRANCH_PROD}" == "$DEPLOY_BRANCH" ]; then
  git push production master -f
  exit 0
fi
```

Here's a sample log I'm getting when finishing the release branch.

[image: sample log]

Comment: I’m lost, what is the issue?

Comment: @MichielLeegwater I'm wondering why it's being pushed to the develop when I'm only finishing release branch using sourcetree which only the master branch should be pushed to the production which is being triggered using post-merge.